# Explanation for the expression of positional encoding in NeRFs

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

I was reading the NeRF paper recently (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.08934.pdf), and under the positional encoding section, I see that the authors propose usage of the following function for transforming the input

$$
\gamma (p) = (sin(2^0 \pi p), cos(2^0 \pi p), sin(2^1 \pi p), ..., sin(2^{L-1} \pi p), cos(2^{L-1} \pi p))
$$

I have two questions regarding this

1. How do we decide what value of $L$ should be chosen?
2. What is the reason for choosing powers of 2 instead of something like

$$ \gamma (p) = (sin(2 * 0 \pi p), cos(2 * 0 \pi p), sin(2 * 1 \pi p), ..., sin(2 * (L-1) \pi p), cos(2 * (L-1) \pi p)) $$